# Correctly update an item at a given index in a state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs), I don't want to add a new item in the array, but I want to modify the item at the index `i` for instance.

Is there a solution other than deep-cloning the entire array like that?

```
const oldList = this.state.list;
let newList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldList));
newList[i] = "foo";
this.setState({list: newList});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Depends on whether item is object or primitve

Comment: You mean the spread operator will only work if the items are primitive types?

Comment: No but shallow copying an array of objects will create multiple arrays of same object references at each index. Also depends on what your expectations are

Comment: But shallow copying an array of primitives is also deep cloning, and I wondered if there was no alternative to that. Besides, I don't know if it creates problems in React if you directly modify the object referenced in a state array, like that for example: `this.state.list[3].text = "foo";`. In itself, the object referenced by `this.state.list[3]` is not in the state.

Comment: Alternatives are `Array#slice()` or spread which are less overhead than JSON methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread.

```
const oldList = this.state.list;
let newList = [...oldList];
newList[i] = "foo";
this.setState({ .list: newList });
```

But the spread will not work if the elements of array are object. Since it will only make a new copy of array that reference to the old object. But in your case, you assign string. So it is primitve type.

---

> So if I'm correct, the spread operator will basically do a deep-cloning

Spread does shallow cloning. Think `array spread` same as creating new array and copy all old value to the new array

```
a = [...b];
```

is the same as

```
a = [];
for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) a.push(b[i]);
```

> because Vue overrides mutation methods on arrays like push(...)

For push, you can also use `spread`

```
a = [...b, 'new item'];
```

And for pop, you can use `splice`

```
a = b.slice(-1, 1);
```

Comment: So if I'm correct, the spread operator will basically do a deep-cloning. If the items are of type object, we must use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldList))`, am I wrong? That's one shortcoming of React compared to Vue.js, because Vue overrides mutation methods on arrays like `push(...)` or `pop(...)` so that you can use them no problem.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. So there's no way to modify the item at index `i` in one line using just one `this.setState(...)`? We must before copy the array and update the item?